How to fix .net Maui iOS xcFramework error?
I have a iOS binding library used in a .net Maui app that builds but the parent project won't compile. The library was converted from Xamarin Forms and worked fine there. Compiling the iOS app on VS for Mac with Intel or M1 produces the error below. More information is given.
Steps to Reproduce
Created MAUI iOS class library Project & added native frameworks on M1 and Intel Mac
Create MAUI app and added the reference of MAUI iOS class Library created in step 1
Compile MAUI app
Expected Behavior
MAUI app created in step 2 should compile
Actual Behavior
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/17.2.8053/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(3,3): Error: clang++ exited with code 1:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"OBJC_CLASS$_MiSnapSDKOverlayView", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in registrar.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_MiSnapSDKOverlayViewUX1", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in registrar.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_MiSnapSDKOverlayViewUX2", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in registrar.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_MiSnapSDKTutorialViewController", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in registrar.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_MiSnapSDKViewController", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in registrar.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_MiSnapSDKViewControllerUX1", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in registrar.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_MiSnapSDKViewControllerUX2", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in registrar.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_MiSnapTutorialViewControllerDelegate", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in registrar.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_MiSnapViewControllerDelegate", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in registrar.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_ShowResultsViewController", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in reg
Environment
Visual Studio for Mac 17.6.12 (build 410)
.NET SDK (Arm64) 8.0.302
.NET Runtime (Arm64) 8.0.6
Any thoughts?

Did you use any third party nuget? Does it happen if you create a default Maui project and iOS binding library?

No 3rd part nuget. The projects were updated from Xamarin.

this similar case may be helpful: NET8 MAUI and deploy for testing to a real device. or you can provide more detailed code about  part in .csproj file .
